# How can i change the email address for sending builds via testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I want to sent an ipa to testers. They are included in the provisioning profile , but i want to change the tester's email address for sending notification from testflight for one of the tester . How can i do this ?

Comment: Invite him using his new email Id

Answer (score 0):

If you are using http://www.testflightapp.com I don't think you can change it, because the user will receive a notification on the email they provided; so the only solution in this case is to send him an invitation to the new email and he shall move his device from the old account or just leave it, and use the new email to receive notifications while the old one will be used to log in to testflight and install the builds.

But maybe you would like to consider moving to the new Apple TestFlight Beta testing which is now fully integrated with the iTunesConnect portal but it needs iOS 8 and later on the tester's device.

[image]